# OSG.JS Deferred Rendering WebGL

Tags: deferred-rendering, osg.js

Is is possible to do deferred rendering in OSG.JS?

I found this example doing it using THREE.JS but I am unable to find one example for OSG.JS.

http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_lights_deferred_pointlights.html

I do have seen the SDK examples doing RTT, but why aren't there any deferred rendering example on the web (or where are they)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made it, it is indeed possible.

The postprocess example is the closest one that I used to achieve it.  I now have normals, depth and colors as G-Buffers and I render the final quad with the composition shader.